# How to run asynchronous code in Cloud Firestore triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm using Cloud Firestore triggers as documented here.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

How do I run asynchronous code from one of these functions? Here is an example of what I would like to do.

```
async function doSomething(data) {
   // ...
}

exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
       await doSomething(change.after.data());
});
```

When I try to deploy this function I get this error message.

```
return await doSomething(change.after.data());
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call an `async` function using `await`, the enclosing function must also be declared `async`.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
       await doSomething(change.after.data());
});
```

Notice where I put `async` on the third line.  This syntax is not unique to Cloud Functions - this is standard JavaScript.